# problem with solving one complex number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

Is $1= -1$ ?
   because,  $1=\sqrt{1}
 =\sqrt{-1×-1}
 =\sqrt{-1}×\sqrt{-1 }
 = i×i 
 = i^2 = -1 $
this can be done with all natural numbers. how this can be? please help me

Comment: "this can be done with all natural numbers" but it can't be done with negative numbers. Or complex numbers. Just forget it.  $\sqrt{a\times b} \ne \sqrt a \times \sqrt b$.  It doesn't.  And if you think about it, no-one one actually ever said it was.  We all all just assumed it was okay.

Comment: @MuhammedHaleem Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

On complex number this step is wrong

$$1=\sqrt{1}$$

since $\sqrt{1}=(e^{2\pi i})^{\frac12}\pm 1$ and also this one

$$\sqrt{-1}=i$$

since $\sqrt{-1}=(e^{\pi i})^{\frac12}=\pm i$.